# transitioning transform attribute of a group element not working in firefox

Tags: css, animation, svg, d3.js, svelte

I am trying to transition `transform` attribute of a group svg element. (i can apply transition on circles itself and it will work, but in a real project i have a group with paths, so I have to apply transform to the group element).

It works well in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox or Safari.

I have read all I could find, and saw this as a solution:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s linear;
-o-transition: -o-transform 1s linear;
transition: transform 1s linear;
```

It does not work for me however.

Full code example [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/465eb8bb8bc740ce8787f45d5e6c2300?version=3.42.4) also.

```
<script>
import { scaleTime, scaleLinear, extent, max, timeFormat,scaleBand} from 'd3';
import { fade, fly } from 'svelte/transition';
    
    let points = []
    

    
    const height = 500;
    
  const xTicks = [1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015];
    const yTicks = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20];
     
  const padding = { top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 20, left: 25 };
    
    $: years = points.map(d => d.year) 
    
    let selectedY = 'birthrate';
    
    $: xScale = scaleBand()
        .domain(years)
        .range([padding.left, 500 - padding.right])
      .padding(0.2);

    $: yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 20])
        .range([500 - padding.bottom, padding.top]); 

    $: innerWidth = 500 - (padding.left + padding.right);
    $: barWidth = innerWidth / xTicks.length;
    
$: points = points.map(d => ({ ...d, birthrateNew:  15 }))
    
    
        function updateData() {
                 points = [
        { id: 1, year: 1990, birthrate: 16.7 },
        { id: 2, year: 1995, birthrate: 14.6 },
        { id: 3, year: 2000, birthrate: 14.4 }, 
        { id: 4, year: 2005, birthrate: 14 },
        { id: 5, year: 2010, birthrate: 13 },
        { id: 6, year: 2015, birthrate: 12.4 }  
    ]; 
    }
    
    function updateData2() {
        selectedY = 'birthrateNew'
    }
    
    $: calcData = points.map(d => {
  return {
    x: xScale(d.year),
    y: yScale(d[selectedY]),
  };
});
    
</script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
{#each calcData as d}
       <g in:fade="{{delay: d.x*2}}" transform="translate({d.x}, {d.y})">
          <circle
          cx={8}
          cy=23
          r= {3}
          stroke='#000'
          fill= '#fff'
          stroke-width='2'
          ></circle>

      </g>
    {/each}

</svg>
<button on:click={updateData}>
    click me
</button>

<button on:click={updateData2}>
    click me
</button>

<style>
    
    g {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s linear;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 1s linear;
    transition: transform 1s linear;
```

}

```
</style>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Firefox doesn't allow to transition the `transform` attribute.
A workaround would be to add the translation to the css as well (you can use custom css properties to pass the coordinates to the style)

```html
<g in:fade="{{delay: d.x*2}}" style="--x: {d.x}px; --y: {d.y}px;">
```

and

```css
g {
  transform: translate(var(--x), var(--y));
  transition: transform 1s linear;
}
```

Note that you need to pass in a unit for the coordinates, but from the code I think `px` should be ok for your usecase.

Comment: I didn't know it is possible! Very new to all of this. Thank you SO much!!